# LESS file watcher gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token during compilation

Tags: less, webstorm

I have set up a LESS file watcher in Webstorm 9.0.2 to take my main.less file and compile it to main.css every time I save edits.

This is how I set it up:

[image]

This is what is in my main.less file

```
body {color:#fff}
```

However I get the following error in console during my compilation phase:

```
"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" main.less

E:\Ornico Work\socialdashboardAngular\app\styles\main.less:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { body {
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

I am new to Webstorm and have very little idea what that error means and how to fix it. Could anyone out there please help me with this if at all possible?

Comment: Check your `LESS` file for the `body` styles. There's something wrong there.

Comment: This is all that is in my less file body {color:#fff};

Comment: You don't need a semi-colon after the closing brace.

Comment: Still doesn't work after removing the ";"

Comment: Add the `LESS` file contents to your question please.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

I added in the LESS file contents below the image showing my watcher set-up

Comment: I have also compiled my less file using a compiler in visual studio and it does succesfully compile so the issue is probably with Webstorm?

Comment: I'm afraid so. And I'm unable to help you with that then.

Comment: Just as a try, delete this `LESS` file, create a new one with exactly the same content, but type it. Don't copy and paste. I'm suspecting that could be an _invisible_ blank char somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use node.js to compile your .less files? Node itself can't do this - you need installing LESS compiler (`npm install less -g`) and specify a path to it as a program in your LESS file watcher.
Like:

```
Program: C:\Users\Your.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd
Arguments: --no-color $FileName$
Workingh dir: $FileDir$
Output paths: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Make sure also to tick `'create output from stdout'`